# Who owns @askdifferent on twitter?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, twitter

There is a [twitter account](http://twitter.com/#!/askdifferent) with our name that has no tweets or followers and isn't following anyone. My fervent hope is that someone in the Ask Different community is squatting on it in case a use for it arises.

Ask Different's [current twitter account](http://twitter.com/#!/stackapple) is bundled with the accounts for all of the rest of the SE sites. Configuring and implementing a new function for the Stack exchange twitter accounts is going to take a lot of time and discussion, but a good first step is at least to make the name of the twitter account consistent with Ask Different's branding.

If the owner of the account is not in our community, we will go through twitter's proper channels to claim the account. But that's the hard way. I'm hoping it'll be easy.

So: do you own @askdifferent or know who does?

Comment: Do you want opinions on the current use of StackApple aired here or should I open a new meta?

Comment: @bmike: Open a new meta question.

Comment: @bmike: hold off for a second, if you would. We're having a discussion with Joel about the twitters right now, there'll be an update pending.

Comment: The StackApple answer at http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/433/please-change-name-of-site-from-apple-to-ask-different/645#645 has been edited pending an answer to this @askdifferent question.

Comment: any luck???????

Comment: @KyleCronin not yet :(

Answer (score 9):

We DO! (We being the [employees of Stack Exchange](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/contact))

After this question was asked, we were able to find and acquire the twitter handle [@askdifferent](https://twitter.com/#!/askdifferent)! From now on, we will be using @askdifferent instead of @stackapple, so remember that if you want to @ reply or mention us.

Psst - if you don't follow @askdifferent already, feel free to do so :-)

Comment: So awesome - great work for all concerned in getting this for the site to have.