# Privileges page refers to wrong site name

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please change name of site from “Apple” to “Ask Different”](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/please-change-name-of-site-from-apple-to-ask-different)

The [Privileges page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges) twice refers to this site as "Apple" as opposed to "Ask Different"; could that be fixed to refer to the site by its current name?